# Is it correct to call mockImplementation() after mockRestore()?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

My goal is to be able to control how a function is mocked between different tests. I may want to mock a function in a test, but not mock it in the following test, then mock it again but in a different way.

Using Jest 29.7.0, in the following example I'm trying to "disable" `console.error()` in tests 1 and 4 but keep its default behavior in tests 2 and 3.

`sum.js`:

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  if (a < 0)
    console.error("a is negative: " + a);
  return a + b;
}
  
module.exports = sum;
```

`sum.test.js`:

```js
const sum = require('./sum');

let consoleSpy;

beforeAll(() => {
  consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'error');
});

afterEach(() => {
  consoleSpy.mockRestore();
});


test('a = -1 but console.error is disabled', () => {
  consoleSpy.mockImplementation();
  expect(sum(-1, 2)).toBe(1);
});

test('a > 0 so no error should be displayed', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});

test('a = -3 but console.error is disabled', () => {
  expect(sum(-3, 2)).toBe(-1);
});

test('a = -4 but console.error is disabled', () => {
  consoleSpy.mockImplementation();
  expect(sum(-4, 2)).toBe(-2);
});
```

However, here is the output I get:

```js
> clean_project@1.0.0 test
> jest

  console.error
    a is negative: -3

      1 | function sum(a, b) {
      2 |   if (a < 0)
    > 3 |     console.error("a is negative: " + a);
        |             ^
      4 |   return a + b;
      5 | }
      6 |

      at error (sum.js:3:13)
      at Object.sum (sum.test.js:24:10)

  console.error
    a is negative: -4

      1 | function sum(a, b) {
      2 |   if (a < 0)
    > 3 |     console.error("a is negative: " + a);
        |             ^
      4 |   return a + b;
      5 | }
      6 |

      at error (sum.js:3:13)
      at Object.sum (sum.test.js:29:10)

 PASS  ./sum.test.js
  ✓ a = -1 but console.error is disabled (2 ms)
  ✓ a > 0 so no error should be displayed (1 ms)
  ✓ a = -3 but console.error is disabled (18 ms)
  ✓ a = -4 but console.error is disabled (4 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.384 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```

I would expect a console output from test 3 but not from test 4.

Apparently the call to `mockImplementation()` worked in test 1 but not in test 4. Is it a bad idea to call `mockImplementation()` after `mockRestore()`?

Changing `beforeAll(...)` into `beforeEach(...)` solves the issue but why would we need to call `spyOn()` for every test?

Comment: _"why would we need to call `spyOn()` for every test?"_ - `mockRestore` [_"restores the original (non-mocked) implementation"_](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore), so if you only apply the mock once before _all_ tests and remove it after _every_ test, only the first test uses it at all. Similarly should read [what `mockImplementation` does](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn) because I doubt it's what you think. Just mock it consistently, then assert on whether or not it's called.

Comment: Ha, my understanding was that the `mockFn` generated by `spyOn` was still linked to `console.error` even after the call to `mockRestore` but that its mock mechanism was simply bypassed. I then expected the call to `mockImplementation` to reactivate the mock mechanism.

Comment: After some tests, I see that `mockReset` which ["replaces the mock implementation with an empty function"](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreset) can be followed by a call to `mockImplementation` in order to change the mock behavior. So I guess the restoration of the original implementation done by `mockRestore` simply requires a new call to `spyOn` to "reactivate" the mock mechanism.